# How to drop all network input on IP with IPTABLES

Tags: linux, security, iptables

With IPTABLES, Is it possible to DROP all network INPUT based on the host or the IP requested?

I want my server reject all incoming transmission if it is the IP who is called E.G.:

- Dropped:

  - `ssh user@192.168.0.10`
  - `http://​192.168.0.10`
- Accepted:

  - `ssh user@server.local`
  - `http://server.local`

The bonus will be it accept only based on the /etc/hosts for its IP…

I know it is possible for HTTP and HTTPS with rules like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 700 --algo bm --string 'Host: 192.168.0.10' -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 443 -m string --to 700 --algo bm --string 'Host: 192.168.0.10' -j DROP
```

and I'm sure it's possible for other protocols, but I don't find how for the moment…

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Your subject line is misleading & inconsistent to actual question.

Comment: How so? Why is it misleading or inconsistent?

Comment: Cause the answer to your q-n in Subject is just `iptables -I INPUT 1 -j DROP`

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible with `iptables`. `iptables` is network-layer tool.

As for SSH, resolving is made on client side, so your server merely doesn't aware if client has typed IP or DNS name.

HTTP-requests contain "Host:" header, so suggested filtering can be done with web-server software.

Comment: It works fine for http with a rule like `iptables -I INPUT -p tcp --dport 80 -m string --to 700 --algo bm --string 'Host: 192.168.0.10' -j DROP`, so it is possible. I just want to figure out how for other protocols…

Comment: As slimsuperhero notes, it can't be done with most protocols.  HTTP is unusual in that some insight into how the client decided to reach the server's IP address is transmitted as part of the request to the server; this is not normal.